# Is it possible to test file download in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

With Laravel 5.4, it's now easy to test file upload: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#testing-file-uploads

Is there a way to test file download too? *Ex: I want to check if a CSV is generated on a click on a button.*

I did not found anything about this. What are the best practices about file download testing in Laravel?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can try with this solution to check if the file was generated while the clicked button

```html
if($request->hasfile('nameOfInput'))
   {
     //your code
   }
```